# Click event not working but works when put in console

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML code.

```
<p>Men's Shirt (on hanger) 
<span class="cart_minus"> - </span>
<span class="cart_add"> + </span> 
<label class="text_right"> 2 Suits </label> </p>
<div class="total"> Total <span>£22.00</span></div> 
<a href="" class="order_now"> Order now </a>
```

JQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.cart_minus').click(function () {
            alert("hai");
});
});
```

When I put same code in console then alert is shown. How could I solve this.

Comment: Where are you including your jQuery library? Also, are these DOM elements being created dynamically?

Comment: Assuming you included jQuery properly, your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/smvvjm1r/

Comment: @Adam I have included the JQuery library. Other Jquery functions are also working properly.

Comment: You get any errors in console? is `.cart_minus` added dynamically?

Comment: @j08691 Yes. My other Jquerys are working

Comment: Are these elements being created dynamically then?

Comment: @Huangism no errors are there in consol

Comment: @Adam yes these elements are created dynamically.

Comment: @sandra then you need to delegate the click event to a parent

Comment: @Adam thanku it works.

Comment: @Huangism thanku for the help

Comment: if the elements are created dynamically, you have to attach the event after they are created

Comment: @LPZadkiel thanku. Got the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be missing the `JQuery` library in your HTML file. Your code works well. Also if they are created dynamically you can use this code below which will add an event listener to the dynamically created element and attach it to the `document` object.

```js
$(document).on('click','.cart_minus', function () {
    alert("hai");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Men's Shirt (on hanger) 
<span class="cart_minus"> - </span>
<span class="cart_add"> + </span> 
<label class="text_right"> 2 Suits </label> </p>
<div class="total"> Total <span>£22.00</span></div> 
<a href="" class="order_now"> Order now </a>
```

Comment: OP states that he included jQuery properly and has no errors in the console

Comment: @j08691 edited my answer based on what OP says to have element created dyncmically

Answer (score 1):

All of your code is working fine for me. Just make sure you added jQuery before using it.

```
<p>Men's Shirt (on hanger) 
<span class="cart_minus"> - </span>
<span class="cart_add"> + </span> 
<label class="text_right"> 2 Suits </label> </p>
<div class="total"> Total <span>£22.00</span></div> 
<a href="" class="order_now"> Order now </a>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cart_minus').on('click', function () {
      alert("hai");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OP states that he included jQuery properly and has no errors in the console

Comment: the point is all of his code works, so there's no other explanation than this one...

Comment: Yes there is and it's been uncovered in the comments above. The OP is adding the elements dynamically.

Comment: Of course there is another explanation ;) they are creating the elements dynamically / on the fly and thus aren't attached to the DOM.

Comment: well right ! my bad